# Jquery - Change value from option value

Tags: jquery

I already have this :

```
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402,True">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430,True">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>
```

But I want to extact the value ",True" like this :

```
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
    <option value="514402">Copie de Musculation</option>
    <option value="514430">Gecko Leopard</option>
    </select>
```

How can I do this with Jquery ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#ListSujet option").each(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().split(",")[0]);
  //console.log($(this).val());
});

$("#ListSujet").on("change",function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402,True">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430,True">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.each($("select").find("option"), function() {
  var splitVal = $(this).val().split(",")
  $(this).val(splitVal[0])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402,True">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430,True">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function of `.attr()` to modify existing value:

```
$('#ListSujet option').attr('value',function(i,o){
    return  o.substring(0, o.indexOf(','))
});
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$('#ListSujet option').attr('value',function(i,o){
   return  o.substring(0, o.indexOf(','))
});

$("#ListSujet").on("change",function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402,True">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430,True">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$("#ListSujet option").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(",True", ""));
}
```