# Jquery - Pass value from Option Value to a table

Tags: jquery

I want to pass a value from option to a table. Here is my code :

```
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402,True">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430,True">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>
```

But I want to extact the value "True" and put him in a table :

```
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>

<td>True<td>
```

How can I do this with Jquery ? Thanks a lot

Comment: How many times are you gonna ask same question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38181967/1719752

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.each($("select").find("option"),function(){
 var splitArr = $(this).val().split(",");
 $(this).val(splitArr[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402,True">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430,True">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#ListSujet option").each(function(){
  var s = $(this).val().split(",");
  $(this).val(s[0]);
  //console.log($(this).val());
  $("tr").append("<td>" + s[1] + "</td>");
});

$("#ListSujet").on("change",function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ListSujet" name="ListSujet">
<option value="514402,True">Copie de Musculation</option>
<option value="514430,True">Gecko Leopard</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    </tr>
</table>
```